# Is there any simple example of the authorization screen written in SDL2

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

Is there any simple example of the authorization screen written in SDL2? It should contains login and password input boxes with cursors and password should be hidden for the password input box.

Is there any simple way to do it in SDL2?

Comment: I made all the Gui element you need to do this, take a look at my repo : https://github.com/jordsti/stigame

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Yes you can do it with pure SDL2, but it will be very time consuming.

**Long answer:**

SDL is a 2D rendering library, and what you expect from it is building a GUI. So if you really want to do it with pure SDL2, you would have to create your own controls, such as TextBox, layout organization, event handling... Really painful.

If you can use external libraries, there are some that provide GUI elements and that run on top of SDL. From what I know, [aedGUI](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=5668) is really simple to use, but it's a C++ library. [GTKSDL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtksdl/) is an interface that permise you to use GTK within SDL.

A third possibility would be to code in your OS's native GUI API, such as WinApi for Windows and Xlib for Linux. You would have to retrieve the handle of your SDL window (fairly easy task), and linking it with the API.